# Set token value for redirect express.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, routes

How can I set a Authorization header in an expressjs response so that it is available on the redirected page?

In my routes.js:

`res.set('access_token', token);
res.redirect("/dashboard");`

Background:

I am trying to get a user login working for my node spa application using Bearer tokens.
To have another layer of security I splitted the signup/login process out of my angular application.

To simplify here let's assume we have an user already registered and the client-side part of the application consists of two routes:

`/login --> static resource with a form that posts to /auth
/dashboard --> single page application, we should get redirected here with our bearer token on successful login; from here, we intercept all XHR within our SPA`

So far, all is working except the redirected page doesn't contain the access_token header, hence the spa route just get blocked in my middleware (like a non authorised request).

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot force a client to pass a specific header with subsequent requests, that's something that needs to be implemented client-side. As an alternative, you could use sessions.

Comment: Okay, sessions are out of game unfortunately. I had a tryout by posting the login with ajax and on success sending the access_token with a window.location.href redirect as query param: /dashboard? + token
That worked and I could access the dashboard (as my middleware checked for the validity of the token) and passed the request to get processed. However I ended up with a URL that contains my jwt token visible in the browser.

Comment: Instead of full-blown sessions, can you use cookies?

Comment: Oh okay. In this case I would use the cookie as a storage mechanism rather than as authentication mechanism, right? So the cookie won't be used to authenticate a user (to prevent XSRF attacks)?

Comment: Never mind, I hadn't considered XSRF issues. Another idea would be to do what you did in your tryout, change the location to `/dashboard?token=...`, and from your SPA strip the query string from the URL by 'redirecting' back to `/dashboard` (after storing the token somewhere, of course). It would expose the token for a brief period of time, but it won't 'stick'.

Comment: Already did that with history.replaceState("/dashboard") in my SPA.
I think I am going to make the login route part of my SPA. And then just handle stuff there.